# Присвоить переменным определенное значения из строки. Python. Пасинг

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

В список попадают строки следующего характера (Название компании + количество сотрудников):

- Genesis 800 сотрудников
- Astound Commerce от 1000 сотрудников
- Innovecs от 500 сотрудников
- Master of Code Global 200 сотрудников
- ...

На выходе нужно получить:

- name = Название компании (1,2,3,4 слова)
- employees = Количество сотрудников (только цифра)

Получаю список, разбиваю его на части:

```
for j in urls:
    driver.get(j['href'])
    company_info = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='company-info']").text
    name = company_info.split() 
    employees = company_info.split()
```

Дальше столкнулся со сложностью присвоит разное к-во элементов переменной и найти определенный элемент(цифру), так как она в разных строках на разном месте.

Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Вы эти данные откуда берете. В каком виде они приходят?

Comment: данные сайта dou.ua: https://jobs.dou.ua/ratings/?from=doufp

Answer (score 0):

Если данные в строках чётко структурированы, и вы можете гарантировать отсутствие неправильных строк - вам подойдёт следующий код. В противном случае он требует дополнительной проверки на "правильность" строки

```py
# просто метод ввода, используемый мной для проверки
a = """ - Genesis 800 сотрудников
 - Astound Commerce от 1000 сотрудников
 - Innovecs от 500 сотрудников 
 - Master of Code Global 200 сотрудников""".split('\n')

for company_info in a:
  # если в начале строки нет символа "-", то срез имеет вид [:-2]
  name = ' '.join(company_info.split()[1:-2])   
  employees = int(company_info.split()[-2])
  print(f'{name} : {employees}')
```

Результат:

```
Genesis : 800
Astound Commerce от : 1000
Innovecs от : 500
Master of Code Global : 200
```